# How can I make Windows 7 PrtScn key to work like in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, ubuntu-12.04

In ubuntu 12.04, <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> key captures the screen and opens a dialog to give a location for saving it as an image file. But in windows, after pressing <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> we need to run some other application like Paint to paste the capture and save. Is there any way to work like Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make windows 7 Print Screen functionality work just like the Ubuntu Print Screen, you need to have just like Ubuntu has, a background process to deal with the click on that key.

I use [FastStone Capture 5.3](http://www.aplusfreeware.com/categories/mmedia/FastStoneCapture.html).

I've selected the "To File" option, so every time I press <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>, a save dialog popups up just like on Ubuntu.

**From the Tray icon:**

1. Right Click Over the Tray Icon;
2. Access "Output";
3. Select the desirable output to use when you hit <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>.

**From the Tool Bar:**

1. Click over "Output Icon";
2. Select the desirable output to use when you hit <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>.

   [image]

<sup>*Additionally, you can set it to "auto save", and you don't even have to use the save dialog.*</sup>

This tool comes with lots of features that really some lots of trouble when it comes to print-screen.

### Useful:

Check the application homepage at [faststone.org](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm).

Check the application [tutorial](http://www.faststone.org/FSCTutorial.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Not in Windows since print screen is not an application per se, it is a function/command. You need to use an application and as a work around since you're using W7, can you use the Snipping Tool?

You can pin it to your taskbar as well!

There is also free applications to help: http://www.etrusoft.com/download.htm

Comment: Currently I'm using snipping tool only to take screenshots in W7. As Ubuntu makes it simple, I'm just expecting any possible ways in W7.